# Grails: Does Domain.executeUpdate flush session?

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I created an application using grails 2.3.11 and hibernate 3.6.10.16, there I have a domain class model like this:

```
class Parent{
    String name
    static hasMany = [fooChildren: Foo]
}

class Foo{
    String name
    String attribute1
    String attribute2

    static belongsTo = [parent: Parent]

    def beforeDelete(){
        LogClass.executeUpdate "UPDATE LogClass SET action=:action WHERE objid=:objid", [action: "DELETE", objid: this.id]
    }
}
```

note that the Foo class has a beforeDelete method that executes an update to a class called LogClass

The problem is when I call something like (inside a service method, of course)

```
Parent p = Parent.get(2) //Parent has 1000 or more fooChildren
p.delete()
```

The deletion process is really slow, and I am wondering if the session is being flushed every time that LogClass.executeUpdate is called.

If so, is there any way to control session flushing?

I've tried with:

```
LogClass.executeUpdate "UPDATE LogClass SET action=:action WHERE objid=:objid", [action: "DELETE", objid: this.id], [flushMode: FlushMode.COMMIT]
```

But when I do so I get the following error

```
No signature of method: LogClass.executeUpdate() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.util.LinkedHashMap, java.util.LinkedHashMap)
```

Is there any way to control session flushing for the executeUpdate method? I know session flush can be controlled with executeQuery or dynamic finders, but I haven't found a way for doing so in executeUpdate.

Any help will be appreciated.

P. S. I know the problem is in the beforeDelete method, because when I remove it, the deletion process is like 100 x faster.

Or probably is the cascading behaviour?